# Axapta V4 batch job table permissions issue

Tags: axapta, user-permissions

Here's the background: when I execute manually a batch job in Axapta V4, I have an error message that say I don't have permissions to modify a record in Batch table.

Here's the problem: I have full admin rights, in my security profile, I have full access on batch table, menu item (basis table security key) and full access in Main menu security, all is checked with full control. I don't understand why with admin rights, I can't run a batch job as if I was not admin.
any ideas, leads ?
thanks for help

Best regards

Comment: Are there licensing configs turned off?

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the error message?

Comment: Licensing configs are on, I can't paste the error message, i'm out of office. thanks for your help guys especially Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the creator can change the batch table record.

This is encoded in the `aosValidateUpdate` method. 
It is also very inconvenient, so uncomment if allowed.